# Can we call a static method with a null object in Java? If so, how?

Tags: java, static

Since static methods can be called directly from the class (i.e. ClassName.methodName), why it is required to call a static method with the object of the class?

If someone knows then, elaborate with example.

```
public static void methodA(){

}
```

Comment: have you tried it yet???

Comment: Did you try `((YourClass)null).methodA()`?

Comment: "...then why it is required to call static method with object..." -- it is **not** required.

Comment: @Kayaman : You are right its running well.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The following code contains an example, in which a static method is called via a `null` reference.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Test test = null;
        test.greeting(); // call with null reference
    }
    public static void greeting() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Because `Test::greeting` is a static method, the expression `test.greeting()` is identical to `Test.greeting()`. For that reason, there is no `NullPointerException` thrown at runtime.

Comment: sir, could please explain why NPE is not throwing ?

Comment: @LMK Attached the full reason in my post which is explained in spec. Please have a look.

Comment: This is fairly self explanatory. The call to greeting is not using the instance (which is null) so no NPE occurs.

Comment: If i change static method to instance method above, then it will throw NullPointerException.

Comment: String s = null; System.out.println(""+s.trim()); throws NPE why ?

Comment: because trim() is not static method

Comment: There are couple of static methods are available in String but u can't make a call on reference to those methods

Answer (score 11):

There is no need for an instance while invoking static member or method.

Since static members belongs to class rather than instance.

[`Example 15.11.1-2. Receiver Variable Is Irrelevant For static Field Access`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#d5e19846)

> The following program demonstrates that a null reference may be used to access a class (static) variable without causing an exception:

The example from spec it self.

```
class Test3 {
    static String mountain = "Chocorua";
    static Test3 favorite(){
        System.out.print("Mount ");
        return null;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(favorite().mountain);
    }
}
```

And the analysis of why it is happening

> Even though the result of favorite() is null, a NullPointerException is not thrown. That "Mount " is printed demonstrates that the Primary expression is indeed fully evaluated at run time, despite the fact that only its type, not its value, is used to determine which field to access (because the field mountain is static).

Comment: String s = null;
    System.out.println(""+s.trim());  throws NPE why ?

Comment: @LMK  `trim()` is not a static method here :) it needs specific instance to perform trim operation.

Comment: @LMK There is no silly questions. Only silly people are there  who afraid to ask a question :) Happy coding.

Comment: Perfect answer using exact reference! That's what  I was looking for. This should be marked as correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 10):

Very well you can call a static method with null object.

See the example below.

```
public class Hashing {

    public static void Hash() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hashing h = null;
        h.Hash();
    }
}
```

Above code snippet will print **hello**

Because at the compile time `h.hash()` will be converted to `Hashing.hash()` since `hash()` is a **static** method.

When I de-compiled `.class` file I got this code.

```
/*
 * Decompiled with CFR 0_114.
 */
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Hashing {
    public static void Hash() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object h = null;
        Hashing.Hash();
    }
}
```

As you can see in the above snippet `h.Hash();` is converted to `Hashing.Hash();`

HTH!!

Comment: perfect explanation! :thumbsup

Answer (score 0):

Yes,and this is a strange situation. Below is the example.

```
public class Test{
    public static String foo(){
     System.out.println("foo");
     return "";
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
            Test t=null;
            t.foo();//no error will be thrown
    }
}
```

Output: foo

Explanation : 
it is expected this should throw a null pointer exception but it just gives you a warning that "The static method  foo() from the type Test should be accessed in a static way". But when executing it will work.