# @Autowire returns null when method is non static in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I'm having some issues with Autowiring in Spring Boot. Some of these issues are related to IntelliJ https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139669. But I noticed something now.

In one class I'm trying to Autowire `UserDetailsService` like this.

```
@Autowired
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

public void someMethod() {
userDetailsService.getUserDetails();
}
```

If the `getUserDetials` method is `static` in `UserDetailsService` like below. Then the Autowiring works.

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsService {
    public static void getUserDetails() {
    System.out.println("Output from UserDetailsService");
}
```

But if the `getUserDetials` method is non-`static` in `UserDetailsService` like below. Then I get the following error `java.lang.NullPointerException: null` for `userDetailsService.getUserDetails()` when I try to use the Autowiring.

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsService {
    public void getUserDetails() {
    System.out.println("Output from UserDetailsService");
}
```

Is it expected behaviour that Autowiring is dependent on the method being `static` or is it just an issue with the IntelliJ, or am I missing something else here?

Comment: What do you mean returns null? Nothing is returning anything. Clarify your question as it makes no sense.

Comment: @AlanHay I've updated the question now.

Comment: Static / non-static has nothing to do with autowiring as it just not happening regardless: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800309/can-we-call-static-method-with-null-object-in-java-if-yes-how So the issue is in your config.UserDetailsService is probable not being picked up as a Sping Bean and so nothing is autowired.

Comment: @AlanHay Now I get it. Since it is `static` there is no need for a `new` instance of the class and therefore I don't need a new instance of the class to use it's methods? Therefore I could remove the `@Autowired` annotation and it will still work?