# Why Static method in a class not giving Null pointer exception when its object is null

Tags: java, static

I surprised with concept why this code works when it has to ideally throw null pointer exception

```
public class Test {
 public static String foo(){
 System.out.println("Test foo called");
 return "";
 }

 public static void main(String args[]){
 Test obj = null;
 System.out.println(obj.foo());
 }
}
```

Comment: Because a static method doesn't need any instance to be called. It's bound to the class, not to any instance. That said, calling a static method on an instance is bad practice, and even more when the instance is null.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800309/can-we-call-static-method-with-null-object-in-java-if-yes-how is not an exact duplicate, but it has a lot of good answers for your question.

Comment: @Lalaland:  Actually, that *is* a suitable duplicate.  Good eyes on finding it.

Comment: Have you considered reading the documentation? Read the Fine Manual! http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#d5e24541

Answer (score 0):

When calling a static method, the type reference is relevant not the instance so obj.foo() and Test.foo() get resolved to the same thing.

Best Practice: **static members should be accessed statically**

> While it is possible to access *static* members from a class instance,
>   it's bad form, and considered by most to be misleading because it
>   implies to the readers of your code that there's an instance of the
>   member per class instance.

https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS2209

Recommend to code as this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
 Test obj = null;
 // ....
 System.out.println(Test.foo());
 }
```